# How to change language or customize template "password_reset_confirm"

Tags: python, django, authentication, logging, reset-password

Im using auth_views.PasswordResetView, when user the user receives the email to reset password, he will see the view "auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView" this view loads the following template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block css %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
{% if validlink %}
    <h3>Change password</h3>
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Restablecer</button>
    </form>
  {% else %}
    <p>
      El link para restablecer tu contraseña es inválido, posiblemente porque ya ha sido utilizado anteriormente.
      Por favor solicita nuevamente restablecer tu contraseña.
    </p>
    <a href="/">Inicio</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

But the template is in english:

[image]

¿Can I change the language of the template?

Answer (score 1):

Django use a default template but you can overwrite it.

By default, it will look for a template in app/registration named password_reset_confirm.html.

If you create your own template, it will be used and you will be able to set language and everything you want